# for loop resets value to 10 after running

Tags: python, for-loop

so I'm making a local multiplayer game that spins a random letter, and this letter will either give you points or remove points from you. This first block sets the number of players and gives each one a value of 10.

```
if (int(player_count) == 1):
  player1Score = 10
  player_scores = [int(player1Score)]
  askname1 = input('What is player 1s name?') 
  player_names = [askname1]

elif (int(player_count) == 2):
 player1Score = 10
 player2Score = 10
 player_scores = [int(player1Score), int(player2Score)]
 askname1 = input('What is player 1s name?') 
 askname2 = input('What is player 2s name?') 
 player_names = [askname1, askname2]  

elif (int(player_count) == 3):
 player1Score = 10
 player2Score = 10
 player3Score = 10
 player_scores = [int(player1Score), int(player2Score), int(player3Score)]
 askname1 = input('What is player 1s name?') 
 askname2 = input('What is player 2s name?') 
 askname3 = input('What is player 3s name?') 
 player_names = [askname1, askname2, askname3]    

elif (int(player_count) == 4):
 player1Score = 10
 player2Score = 10
 player3Score = 10
 player4Score = 10
 player_scores = [int(player1Score), int(player2Score), int(player3Score), int(player4Score)]
 askname1 = input('What is player 1s name?') 
 askname2 = input('What is player 2s name?') 
 askname3 = input('What is player 3s name?') 
 askname4 = input('What is player 4s name?')
 player_names = [askname1, askname2, askname3, askname4]
```

This block runs the code and initializes the for loop to go through all of the players. After the while loop runs, the next time it runs, the player score is reset to 10. I'm trying to make it so after the for loop runs for the player, it adds the specified value to the player's score, and not reset after each loop.

```
def multiplayer_game():
  global player_scores
  if (int(player_count) == 1):
   totalPot = 200
  if (int(player_count) == 2):
   totalPot = 300
  if (int(player_count) == 3):
   totalPot = 400
  if (int(player_count) == 4):
   totalPot = 500  
   print('INSTRUCTIONS: Each round the pot will reset to 30. When the total pot of', totalPot, 
   'reaches 0, the game ends.')
   print()

  continuegameq = input('Press any key to start the game:')
  pot = 30
  while (continuegameq):
    pot = 30
    for i in player_names:
      print(str(i) + 's turn.')
      for g in player_scores:
        letter = random.choice(dreidel)
      if (g < 0): 
        g = 0
      if (letter == "Hey"):
        g += pot/2
        pot /= 2
        print('You got a Hey. Take the half the pot! The pot now has', int(pot), 'pieces.')
        print(str(i), 'now has', int(g), 'peices.')
        totalPot -= g + 10

      elif (letter == "Gimel"):
        g += pot
        pot -= pot
        print('You got a Gimel. Take the whole pot! The pot now has', int(pot), 'pieces.')
        print(str(i), 'now has', int(g), 'peices.')
        totalPot -= g + 10

      elif (letter == "Nun"):
        g += 0
        pot += 0
        print('You got a Nun. Do nothing. The pot has', int(pot), 'pieces.')
        print(str(i), 'now has', int(g), 'peices.')
        totalPot -= g + 10

      elif (letter == "Shin"):
        g -= 1
        pot += 1
        print('You got a Shin. Put 1 piece in the pot. The pot now has', int(pot), 'pieces.')
        print(str(i), 'now has', int(g), 'peices.')
        totalPot -= g + 10

      continuegameq = False
      print()
      continuegameq = input('Press any key for the next turn:')
```

Comment: You want the changes to `g` be preserved in `player_scores`? // Besides that, the code in the first listing cries for a list (or dictionary) and a loop.

Comment: Yes. Make g + the value of the letter = the new player score

Comment: I just tried to make g the new value of the score per the index in the list. However, this still didn't work, I'm still stuck.  @phipsgabler

Comment: It appears you have some fundamental misunderstanding about the nature of references and values. I'm sorry, but I lack the time to guide you. Are you taking any courses, maybe? Otherwise I can just recommend trying to find some material online (there are some lectures about pointers in the excellen "Programming Paradigms" course from Stanford on YouTube, for example).

Comment: @phipsgabler yeah I'm a student taking a python course now. I will ask my teacher for further guidance and explanations of concepts. Thanks.